Need help working with custom scripts in laravel splade get vue warn scripts error
currently the only way i can display my map is by adding a full html code and remove the
 <x-layout>

</x-layout>

want to use splade blade format for the code not going back to full html
my html code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <style>
        .text-center {
            text-align: center;
        }
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 600px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css' crossorigin='' />
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder@2.4.0/dist/Control.Geocoder.js'></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/">
    Home
</a>
    <h1 class='text-center'>Cholera Concentration Map</h1>

    <div id='map'></div>

    <script src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js' crossorigin=''></script>
    <script>
        let map, markers = [];
        /* ----------------------------- Initialize Map ----------------------------- */
        function initMap() {
            map = L.map('map', {
                center: {
                    lat: -19.0154,
                    lng: 29.1549,
                },

                zoom: 6
            });

            L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '© OpenStreetMap'
            }).addTo(map);

            map.on('click', mapClicked);
            initMarkers();
        }
        initMap();

        /* --------------------------- Initialize Markers --------------------------- */
        function initMarkers() {
            const initialMarkers = <?php echo json_encode($initialMarkers); ?>;

            for (let index = 0; index < initialMarkers.length; index++) {

                const data = initialMarkers[index];
                const marker = generateMarker(data, index);
                marker.addTo(map).bindPopup(`<b>${data.position.lat},  ${data.position.lng}</b>`);
                map.panTo(data.position);
                markers.push(marker)
            }
        }

        function generateMarker(data, index) {
            return L.marker(data.position, {
                    draggable: data.draggable
                })
                .on('click', (event) => markerClicked(event, index))
                .on('dragend', (event) => markerDragEnd(event, index));
        }

        /* ------------------------- Handle Map Click Event ------------------------- */
        function mapClicked($event) {
            console.log(map);
            console.log($event.latlng.lat, $event.latlng.lng);
        }

        /* ------------------------ Handle Marker Click Event ----------------------- */
        function markerClicked($event, index) {
            console.log(map);
            console.log($event.latlng.lat, $event.latlng.lng);
        }

        /* ----------------------- Handle Marker DragEnd Event ---------------------- */
        function markerDragEnd($event, index) {
            console.log(map);
            console.log($event.target.getLatLng());
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>

want to know how i can use scripts inside the x-layout blade layout in splade i tried using x-scripts from the documentation but this did not work
